# html ignores files paths

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Online Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="./sass/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img alt="shop logo" src="./img/header-logo.webp" width="50px" height="50px"/>
      <input type="text" class="header-search">
    </header>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

File structure:

[image]

Path in WebStorm:
[image]

And idk why but html automatically cuts each path to file to file name only.
In code: `./img/header-search.webp`. In devtools: `header-search.webp`
And if I change the path in devtools then it works. This problem appears with any file type. How can I fix it?

Comment: start path with a point `./` mean current directory...

Comment: @MisterJojo ye I know and thats why I wrote ./<folder>/<file>

Comment: Try without the "./" so something like this:  <img  src="img/header-logo.webp" />

Comment: @adabuyaman doesn't work. I tried all ways to set the path but none of them worked

Comment: WebStorm sees the path when I type it btw

Comment: **html5** syntax is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="sass/style.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but I'm really dumb xD. In link tag I wrote type="style/css" instead of type="text/css" and the problem was here. Be attentive guys and don't be like me xD